# Django debug mode False then the page doesn't work

Tags: python, django, web-applications, deployment

I'M using Django in local server. If I turned debug mode to False, the web page is not available.(500)  But it works perfect if the debug mode is true.  What can I do to fix this?

Comment: could you at least post the view code?

Comment: just a few render static htmls.

Comment: Look at the error logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it's django 1.5 it could be related to allowed host setting

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-ALLOWED_HOSTS

Comment: If there are no other problems other than setting DEBUG = False, then this is the correct answer. ALLOWED_HOSTS is a required setting if DEBUG = False.

Comment: Mine doesn't look like the Allowed host is the culprit. Still experiencing the issue.